# How do I use calibre to create page-numbered ebooks for Kindle?

Tags: calibre, kindle-paperwhite

I know Kindle can use APNX files for page numbering, and I've been told Calibre can generate those for AZW books, and I actually followed a tutorial on Reddit where they tell you to go to Calibre's Preference and add a "pages" column with certain attributes, but in the end, no APNX file was generated.

In fact, the only way to get page numbers that I know is through the APNX plugin, which not only doesn't work anymore but even when in the Calibre versions it did, would only generate APNX of MOBI books and eventually would refuse to work with certain books.

So, any help on this subject would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Calibre KFX Output plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=272407), which requires [Kindle Previewer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000765261), to generate a KFX file with page numbers.

If the original epub contains an [NCX pagelist](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/NCX#PageList), an [Adobe Pagemap](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Page-map#Page-map) or an [epub3 NAV page-list](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/EPub_3#Page_numbers), the converter will automatically generate correct page numbers.

If the original book doesn't contain page numbers, select **KFX Output > Create Approximate Page Numbers** to have the KFX converter insert fake page numbers.

Comment: Ah, ok, I only forgot to mention one thing, which is I wanted the books to be in either mobi or AZW, because I never sideload my books and only these formats are accepted by whispersync AFAIK.

Comment: I say these because once I got a data corruption which made me lose more than 500 notes in a single book that was sideload ed, and since then I only use whispersync